# For a matrix, how to prove its max eigenvalue max inner product with any matrix which is semidefinite and has a trace less than 1?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite

How to prove the equation in (22) in [1801.09344](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09344)? For simplicity, I re-describe it here:

$$\max_{P \succeq0, \operatorname{trace}(P) \leq 1}\! \langle A,P\mkern1.5mu\rangle= \lambda_+(A)$$

where $\lambda_+(A)$ is the maximum eigenvalue of A.

Comment: How do you define $\langle A, P \rangle$?  Is it $\langle A, P \rangle = \text{Tr}(AP)$?

Comment: @RobertLewis No, I think it's sum over element-wise product. i.e. $sum_{i,j} A_{i,j}P_{i,j}$

Answer (score 2):

For $P$ a self adjoint operator, consider a diagonalization 
$$P=\sum \mu_i |v_i \rangle \langle v_i|$$ 
where $|v_i \rangle$ is an orthonormal basis of the space. For $A$ any matrix, we have 
$$\langle A, P\rangle = \sum \mu_i \langle A v_i, v_i\rangle$$
If $A$ is self adjoint with  $\lambda_{+}(A)$ its largest eigenvalue, and $P\succeq 0$ ( that is $\mu_i \ge 0$ for all $i$) we have 
$$\langle A, P\rangle\le \sum \mu_i \cdot \lambda_{+}(A)\langle v_i, v_i \rangle = \lambda_{+}(A)\cdot \sum \mu_i = \lambda_{+}(A) \cdot trace(P)$$

Moreover, if $e$ is a unit eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda_{+}(A)$ we have for $P=|e\rangle \langle e|$, $trace(P)=1$ and $\langle A,P\rangle = \langle A e, e\rangle = \lambda_{+}(A)$

Comment: ,Thanks a lot for your answer! May I configure that your ⟨vi| is transpose of the orthonormal basis |vi⟩ ? Also, could you help me in giving a formal proof of the $<A,P> \leq \sum u_i \lambda_+(A)<v_i,v_i>$ ? I only have a rough idea

Comment: @user3946626: No worries! What you use is $(Av,v)\le \lambda_{+}(A) \cdot (v,v)$ for any vector $v$. Note that you also need $\lambda_{+}(A) \ge 0$ if you consider $trace(P)\le 1$, and not only $=1$.

Comment: I still do not understand. To solve my confusion, I asked another question here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807842/how-to-prove-for-any-vector-v-and-matrix-a-langle-av-v-rangle-le-lambda/2807862#2807862,  and it seems that $<Av,v> \leq \lambda_+(A) $ is not always true. Perhaps I misunderstood your word?